# Referencing Component instances from Spring Boot Configuration classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**Please note:** I understand 100% that this questions is very *similar* to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710526/how-to-apply-spring-boot-filter-based-on-url-pattern). My question is *similar* (I want to configure filter paths/urls inside a Spring Boot application), however the accepted answer on that question presumes a slightly different yet significant different configuration than what I have set up.

---

So I have a *working* filter that works great:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Slf4j
class DataModeFilter implements Filter {
    @Autowired
    List<EndpointConfig> endpointConfigs

    @Autowired
    MyAppProperties myAppProperties

    @Override
    void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        log.trace("Initializing the ${this.class.name} filter...")
    }

    @Override
    void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.trace("Do some stuff")
    }

    @Override
    void destroy() {
        log.trace("Destroying the ${this.class.name} filter...")
    }
}
```

I also have a `@Configuration` class (for programmatic DI) but I do not need to write a `@Bean`-annotated method inside of it for the `DataModeFilter`, because `DataModeFilter` is a `@Component` (which Spring DI takes care of automagically for us).

I now want to only apply my `DataModeFilter` to endpoints exposed at the path `v1/data`. According to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39710789/4009451) in that other question, I need to add the following to my `@Configuration` (DI) class:

```
@Configuration
class MyAppConfigurator {
    // Lots of other @Beans declared up here

    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean()

        registration.setFilter(dataModeFilter())
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/v1/data/*")
        registration.addInitParameter("paramName", "paramValue")
        registration.setName("dataModeFilter")
        registration.setOrder(1)

        registration
    } 

    @Bean(name = "dataModeFilter")
    Filter dataModeFilter() {
        // How to refer to my @Component-annotated DataModeFilter instance?!?
    }
}
```

**However, my `DataModeFilter` is not a `@Bean` in that class, so how do I reference it for my `FilterRegistrationBean`?**

Answer (score 1):

```
@Configuration    
class MyAppConfigurator {
    @Autowired
    DataModeFilter filter;
}
```

or simply

```
private final DataModeFilter filter;
public MyAppConfigurator(DataModeFilter filter) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhijit (+1) - except `MyAppConfigurator` is annotated by `@Configuration`...can I still `@Autowire` it with a `DataModeFilter` instance?!

Comment: Didn't I just say you can?

Comment: No :-) in your code example above, you have not annotated `MyAppConfigurator` with `@Configuration`... so I'm wondering whether adding `@Configuration` will mess things up for Spring...can you please confirm (and update your code example if need be!) either way? Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't write the complete code for you, true: That's your job. Please try it and come back if there's a problem with my suggestion. There's a difference between helping and babysitting.

Comment: Thanks @Abhjit now if you realize I'm using Groovy. Please reformat your code samples to not contain semi-colons or access modifiers.