# How to apply Filter to specific @RestController method?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I implemented [Filter](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/7.1.2.Final/javax/servlet/Filter.html?is-external=true) to encrypt request/response body. How may I apply that Filter not to every request but only some specific methods of a [@RestController](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html)?

Comment: why not just implement your code in that specific method of that rest controller?

Comment: Because it has to be applied to specific endpoints/methods of different @RestController. It is of course desirable the endpoint receive instances of entities (non encrypted).

Comment: [Register the filter for a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710526/how-to-apply-spring-boot-filter-based-on-url-pattern?rq=1) (not a method).

Comment: Thanks @AndrewS, that is one of the options indeed. I was curious whether there was a "type safe" way (save of a path modification for example).