# Spring boot filter always mapped to /*

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, filter

In my Spring Boot application I have the following filter class

```
public class UserIdAuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
    // all the handling
}
```

I am not using any annotation on this class, I am using applicationContext.xml to define this bean as following:

```
<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
                <security:filter-chain  pattern="/lms/s/reward/*" filters="UIDAuthenticationFilter"/>
    </security:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
<bean id="UIDAuthenticationFilter" class="com.mycompany.security.filter.UserIdAuthenticationFilter" >
</bean>
```

I created another class that is used to load this xml configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public class XMLConfiguration {
}
```

Now when I start my application i can see in the logs that the filter is being loaded from applicationContext.xml:

```
15:06:01.516 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO - Mapping filter: 'UIDAuthenticationFilter' to: [/*]
```

It is clearly saying that the filter is mapped to /*
So  the filter is being called for each request, I dont want this behaviour, I want that my filter should only be called for the pattern that I provided in the applicationContext.xml. (`/lms/s/reward/*`)

Also I don't want [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710526/how-to-apply-spring-boot-filter-based-on-url-pattern) solution. Because I have to configure the filter in the applicationContext.xml, not in the java code.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Yes you do want [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39710526/how-to-apply-spring-boot-filter-based-on-url-pattern) solution... The fact that it is written in Java doesn't mean you cannot translate the same in XML... Just define a bean for the `FilterRegistration`  bean.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Thanks. Worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution for this. I've changed my applicationContext.xml as below:

```
<bean id="MyFilter" class="com.mycompany.security.filter.MyFilter">
</bean>
<bean id="filterRegistrationBean"
    class="org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean">
    <property name="filter" ref="MyFilter">
    </property>
    <property name="urlPatterns" value="/lms/s/*">
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now my Filter is geting mapped to `/lms/s/*` , Thanks a lot to @M.Deinum

Comment: THANK YOU.  I'm added some keywords to help future generations.   OncePerRequestFilter implements Ordered   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean custom filter